# Compound generic view in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm working on my first Django project. I need to display a compound page containing both sides of a one-to-many database relationship. Trying to be as Django-y as possible, I considered (class based) generic views. Since none of the built-in generic views had anything similar, I hacked together a compound generic view using `SingleObjectMixin` and `MultipleObjectMixin`, which also meant I had to extend the base `View` class.

Looking back, this seems like a lot of work for something that (in my opinion) should be quite trivial, and I assumed that I took the wrong path to solve that problem. So I'm turning to the SO community for help:

- What would be the correct solution for this problem?
- How would you go about solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't use a `DetailView` and then iterate over the many side of the relationship (via `object.relationship.all()`). If you need pagination through the many side objects it gets fiddly; you can use `ListView` and `SingleObjectMixin` together to do it (there are [instructions in Django's development documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview)). Without a bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve it's difficult to know how I'd likely attack the problem :-)

Comment: @JamesAylett Actually, I was looking for something exactly like what's demonstrated in that document. Now I just have to check if it works in 1.4. I feel so dumb that I haven't found that document earlier!

Comment: should work fine in 1.4 as it was based on work I'd done on a released site when I wrote the original draft :-) always good to check though…

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `DetailView` (which uses `SingleObjectMixin`), and access the related object through its access attribute on the instance in the template:

```
<h2>Main Object</h2>
<p>{{ object.some_field }}</p>
<h2>Related Object</h2>
{% with related=object.related_whatever %}
    <p>{{ related.some_field }}</p>
    <p>{{ related.other_fied }}</p>
{% endwith %}
```